# How to upgrade RAM in live running ubuntu server?

Tags: linux-server

I want to know how can I upgrade RAM of my live running physical server.

I had ubuntu operating system on my physical server, now I wanted to upgrade it to 8GB.

How can It possible ?

Any alternate solution, so my running process not disturbed.

Comment: Is it a physical server or virtual server ?

Comment: Is this just a physical ubuntu server, or is it a virtual machine? If so, what virtualisation solution are you using?

Comment: You won't be able to upgrade the memory without doing a restart.

Comment: Upgrading a RAM takes about 3 minutes. Your live system may well die and then resurrect.

Comment: @Ramhound, any alternate solution, to keep alive server processes.

Comment: @user1635700  - What you want is not possible with the hardware your using.

Comment: You should not ever add RAM to a live system.  What are you running that is so important that you cant take it down for 20 minutes at 4:00 AM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to hotswap RAM while the system is running unless you are using high class enterprise level hardware.

Unless you have 2 servers for failover, your processes will need to be restarted when the server restarts.